# openam with database

Tags: database, opensso

I have a requirement that openam should access users and groups from a MySQL database. In the openam GUI for New Data Store -> Database Repository (Early Access), I could see some configurations related to this. But I am not aware about how to map fields from two or three of MySQL tables (users and groups) to the corresponding attributes of openAM. Also what are the mandatory or optional fields for keeping user and group information? Somebody please point me to good documentation on this.

Also I have a couple of basic queries.

1. Is it possible to keep policy information in database?
2. Is it possible to create users, groups and assign policy information from a web application deployed differently (through JSP / servlet). Does the OpenSSO APIs allows to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Database data store is very primitive (hence it's Early Access), and it is very likely that it won't fit your very specific needs. In that case you can always implement your own Data Store implementation (which can be tricky, I know..), here's a guide for it:
http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/10.0.0/dev-guide/index.html#chap-identity-repo-spi

Per your questions:

1) the policies are stored in the configuration store, and I'm not aware of any ways to store them in DataBase

2) yes, there are some APIs which let you perform some changes with the identities stored in the data store, but OpenSSO/OpenAM is not an identity management tool, so it might not be a perfect fit for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple but sparse documentation makes it a bit tough to do. Check out: http://rahul-ghose.blogspot.com/2014/05/openam-database-connectivity-with-mysql.html

Basically you need to create a MySql database and 2 tables for this. Include all variables you see in the User Configuration dropdown in the Mysql user table, it is okay to remove a few attributes.